# Unicorn log analyzer

Tags: logging, heroku, analytics, thin, unicorn

Are there any robust Unicorn (Thin additionally would be a plus) web log analyzers that are comparable to the Apache offerings?  In other words, I'd like to capture details such as the following at a glance beyond simply relying on Google Analytics, etc:

```
 -General Statistics, Bandwidth etc.
 -Top Visitors
 -Requested files
 -Requested static files, images, swf, js, etc.
 -Referrers URLs
 -404 or Not Found
 -Operating Systems
 -Browsers and Spiders
 -Hosts, Reverse DNS, IP Location
 -HTTP Status Codes
 -Referring Sites
```

In this example I have Unicorn logs draining into a central rsyslog server from Heroku and would like to be able to treat this input with a log analyzer similar to what I would normally run for Apache as a sanity check against Google Analytics results that can be skewed due to JS dependency, etc.

In other words, I want to run a log analyzer on a local server that is receiving all of the Heroku Unicorn and other logging facilities so I'm not attempting to run an analyzer directly on Heroku Cedar.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the logs from Heroku are already in Apache compatible format. So, if you already have a syslog drain setup, I believe you should be able to use any existing Apache log file analyser of your choice on your local logs.

Is that what you want?